# How do I set a rule for the minimum quantity allowed by specific category?

Tags: magento, checkout, minimum

I am creating a Magento website. Now I need to setup a rule which will allow customers to buy a minimum quantity within a category. So I understand it is a category level rule. For example a customer can buy minimum 6 product from the shirt category.

I have tried editing `link.phtml`, but it only allows me to set the rule within the whole website not by category.

Here is my code:

```
<?php if ($this->EnableOnepagecheckout()):?>
<?php if(Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getItemsQty() >= 1):?> 
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Proceed to Checkout') ?>" class="button btn-proceed-checkout btn-checkout<?php if (!$this->checkEnable()){ echo 'no-checkout'; }?>"<?php if (!$this->checkEnable()){ echo ' disabled="disabled" ';} ?> onclick="window.location='<?php echo $this->getOnepageCheckoutUrl() ?>';"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Proceed to Checkout') ?></span></span></button>
<?php endif?>
<?php endif?>
```

Comment: In the admin, you can set a default "Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart" for all products, and then in each product you can override this value with a product-specific value.  You can set it under Inventory -> "Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart".  Magento makes this easy on a product level...but I think the fact that a product can be in multiple categories makes this tough to do it by category.  You can manually go through a category and set this value for those products...or write a script to automate that process.

Answer (score 0):

As a variant, you could add an observer for event 'sales_quote_item_qty_set_after' and describe the whole logic of the process in it. But note that there may be a conflict in case a product belongs to several categories simultaneously while min_add_qty is different for each category.